# SELECT values which are not null from JSONB field in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am unable to select non-null values from a property inside a JSONB field in Postgres 9.5

`SELECT data->>'property' FROM mytable WHERE data->>'property' IS NOT NULL;`

I also tried using NOTNULL.

I receive error 42883 when I run either of these. "ERROR: Operator does not exist. JSONB->>boolean Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: Are you sure you don't use 9.4? In 9.4 the `->>` operator has lower precedence than the `IS [NOT] NULL` (so your query is parsed as `data ->> ('property' IS NOT NULL`)). I have no 9.5 instance right now to test, but it seems (from @Patrick 's answer) that this might be an improvement introduced in 9.5. In 9.4 the simplest workaround is to use parenthesis: `(data->>'property') IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Change is indeed happened: [9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE) vs. [9.5](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE) (`->` and `->>` is within the *(any other)* operator).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I quickly tested your question and found no problem:

```
patrick@brick:~$ psql -d test
psql (9.5.0)
Type "help" for help.

test=# CREATE TABLE mytable (id serial PRIMARY KEY, data jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
test=# INSERT INTO mytable (data) VALUES
('{"ip": "192.168.0.1", "property": "router"}'),
('{"ip": "127.0.0.1", "property": "localhost"}'),
('{"ip": "192.168.0.15", "property": null}');
INSERT 0 3
test=# SELECT * FROM mytable;
 id |                     data
----+----------------------------------------------
  1 | {"ip": "192.168.0.1", "property": "router"}
  2 | {"ip": "127.0.0.1", "property": "localhost"}
  3 | {"ip": "192.168.0.15", "property": null}
(3 rows)

test=# SELECT data->>'property' FROM mytable WHERE data->>'property' IS NOT NULL;
 ?column?
-----------
 router
 localhost
(2 rows)
```

Note that in `jsonb` a `NULL` value should be specified precisely so on input (as in the sample above), not in some quoted version. If the value is not `NULL` but an empty string or something like `'<null>'` (a string) then you should adapt your test to look for that: `WHERE data->>'property' = ''`. If this is the case you could consider using `jsonb_set()` to set such values to a true json `null`.

Incidentally, you could also do:

```
SELECT data->>'property' FROM mytable WHERE data->'property' IS NOT NULL;
```

i.e. test the `jsonb` value for `NULL` rather than its cast to `text`. More efficient, certainly on larger tables. This obviously only works on true `null`s.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the JSON here but I can make a few comments. 1. Other queries on the JSONB work well. 2. It looks like most the data in this particular attribute of the JSON is defined as <null>

Comment: I don't think my JSON property is being set to `null` in the way you posted. Is there a way to check for an empty string?

Comment: + for mentioning -> instead of a text type cast (->>) as most people just copy the examples with type casting when they really do not need the overhead!

Answer (score 5):

First check the JSON key is not null (using a single ->) its important this goes first.

Then check if the value is empty or not (using the double ->>) there's a few possible empty values so add checks for whatever you consider empty

so the asked query becomes.

```
SELECT data->>'property' 
FROM mytable 
WHERE data->'property' IS NOT NULL
    AND data->>'property' <> ''
    AND data->>'property' <> '{}'
    AND data->>'property' <> '[]';
```